# How to pair rows in a data frame with many columns using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe containing multiple observations from the control and the experimental cohorts with replicates for each subject.

Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
subject  cohort    replicate val1   val2
  A     control       1       10     0.1
  A     control       2       15     0.3
  A     experim       1       40     0.7
  A     experim       2       45     0.9
  B     control       1        5     0.3     
  B     experim       1       30     0.0
  C     control       1       50     0.5
  C     experim       1       NA     1.0
```

I'd like to pair each control observation with its corresponding experimental one for each value to calculate the ratio between the pairs. The desired output would look something like this:

```
subject  replicate   ratio_val1   ratio_val2
  A         1           4             7
  A         2           3             3
  B         1           6             0
  C         1          NA             2
```

Ideally, I'd like to see this implemented with dplyr and pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` by reshaping the dataset to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), subject+replicate~cohort, value.var = c("val1", "val2"))[,
          paste0("ratio_", names(df1)[4:5]) := Map(`/`, .SD[,  
      grep("experim", names(.SD)), with = FALSE], 
       .SD [, grep("control", names(.SD)), with = FALSE])][, (3:6) := NULL][]
#    subject replicate ratio_val1 ratio_val2
# 1:       A         1          4          7
# 2:       A         2          3          3
# 3:       B         1          6          0 
# 4:       C         1         NA          2
```

Or after grouping with 'subject', 'replicate', we loop over the 'val' columns and divide the corresponding elements of 'val' for 'experim' with that of 'control'

```
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD[, grep("val", names(.SD)), with = FALSE], 
   function(x) x[cohort =="experim"]/x[cohort =="control"]) ,
               by = .(subject, replicate)]
```

---

Or we can use `gather/spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   gather(Var, Val, val1:val2) %>%
   spread(cohort, Val) %>% 
   group_by(subject, replicate, Var) %>%
   summarise(ratio = experim/control) %>% spread(Var, ratio)
#    subject replicate  val1  val2
#      <chr>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1       A         1     4     7
# 2       A         2     3     3
# 3       B         1     6     0
# 4       C         1    NA     2
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, @akrun! I see that the group_by yields just one row in each group. So the alternative would be `df1 %>%
   gather(Var, Val, val1:val2) %>%
   spread(cohort, Val) %>% mutate(ratio=experim/control) %>% select(-control,-experim) %>% spread(Var, ratio)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarize_at` function from `dplyr` to summarize columns `val1` and `val2` after grouping the data by `subject` and `replicate`. Use `[cohort == ...]` to pick up the values at the experiment and control group correspondingly for division:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(subject, replicate) %>% 
       summarize_at(vars(contains('val')), 
                    funs("ratio" = .[cohort == "experim"]/.[cohort == "control"]))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: subject [?]
#
#   subject replicate val1_ratio val2_ratio
#    <fctr>     <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1       A         1          4          7
# 2       A         2          3          3
# 3       B         1          6          0
# 4       C         1         NA          2
```

Comment: Thank @Psidom! When there is only one value column, [the answer is so simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295777/how-to-pair-rows-in-a-data-frame-in-r-with-dplyr). Is there as a simple solution for the case of multiple value columns?

Comment: In dplyr 0.4.3, I do not see summarize_at.  Do you mean summarize_each?

Comment: I am using `dplyr` 0.5.0. And `summarize_at` is a new API for `dplyr` so if you upgrade your `dplyr` package, you will see it and also, `summarize_each` will be deprecated in the future, while you can still use it now, you'd be better get used to these new APIs.

Comment: And for your first comment, when there is just one value column, you can reshape your data and get two columns, then divide them. However for multiple value columns, this is not so obvious. After you reshape your data, you will get four columns here, and the code will not be as short anyway.

Comment: If you prefer to work with `summarize_each` temporarily, you can use it as `df %>% group_by(subject, replicate) %>% summarize_each(funs(ratio = .[cohort == "experim"]/.[cohort == "control"]), -cohort)` which gives the same results as `summarize_at`.

Comment: As you suggested, I upgraded to dplyr 0.5.0. Your solution worked flawlessly!